# Jade equivalent for csrf token in Sails

Tags: pug, csrf, sails.js

From the examples, using the default ejs engine, the hidden input required for csrf protection is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
```

What is the jade equivalent? Is it:

```
input(type="hidden", name="_csrf", value='#{_csrf}')
```

Thanks.

---

EDIT: I've tried both `value='#{_csrf}'` and `value=#{_csrf}` and I'm pretty sure neither are correct as they don't display the right csrf token.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
input(type="hidden", name="_csrf", value=_csrf)
```

That should output the token for you.

Comment: Oh perfect, I don't know how I overlooked that. +1

Comment: thanks a lot , I almost send half s day figuring this  out :)